# HashMap with ArrayLists values returning Null on Get() call

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `HashMap` that stores an object I created as a key and maps to an `ArrayList` of similar objects.

However, I am calling the get method, and using jGrasp's debugger I can clearly see that the key I am using in `get()` exists and indeed maps to an `array` but the only value I can get is a `null` value.

Here is where I am getting the `null` value.

```
public List<Entry> query(Record query) {
     List<Entry> candList;
     Entry key = new Entry(makeKey(query));

     candList = map.get(key);

     return candList;
}
```

Here is where I am populating the `HashMap` from a main store.

```
for(int i = 0; i < main.size(); i++) {
    if(main.get(i).isActive()) {
        values.clear();
        tmp = new Entry(main.get(i).record());
        key = new Entry(Record.make(tmp.entity(),tmp.relation(),wild));

        if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
            for(int v = 0; v < main.size(); v++) {
                value = main.get(v);

                if(key.entity().equals(value.entity()) && key.relation().equals(value.relation())) {
                    values.add(value);
                 }                        
            }

            map.put(key,new ArrayList(values));
        }
    }
}
```

`Entry` is a wrapper class that defaults to the `equals()` method of its inner object, here.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null){ 
        return false; 
    }
    else if(o instanceof Record){
        Record r = (Record) o;
        return this.entity.equals(r.entity) && this.relation.equals(r.relation) && this.property.equals(r.property);
    }

    else return false;
}
```

I also have a hashcode written for the object here.

```
int h = 0;
public int hashCode() {

    int hash = h;

    if(h != 0) 
    return hash;

    String len = entity.concat(relation.concat(property));
    for(int i = 0; i < len.length(); i++)
        hash = hash * 31 +(int)len.charAt(i);

    return hash;
}
```

For a little clarification, the `Entry` object holds an object of type `Record` that contains three immutable `String`s, hence where the `hashCode` equation comes from.

For further clarification someone asked to see the entire `Entry` class.

```
private static class Entry {
    private static boolean active;
    private Record rec;

    public Entry(Record r){
      this.rec = r;
      this.active = true;
    }    

    public String entity() {
      return rec.entity;
    }

    public String relation() {
      return rec.relation;
    }

    public String property() {
      return rec.property;
    }

    public Record record(){
      return this.rec;
    }

    public boolean isActive(){
    return this.active;
    }

    public void deactivate(){
    this.active = false;
    }

    public void activate(){
    this.active = true;
    }

    public boolean equals(Entry e) {
      return this.rec.equals(e.record());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
      return this.rec.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
      return rec.toString();
    }
}
```

There are some collisions occurring in my `HashMap` but I know that's not supposed to be too much of an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the equals method implementation of the Entry class?

Comment: `o instanceof Record` o will never be of instance Record, it receive and Entry oobject by parameter instead of Record

Comment: Can you post your whole Entry class please?

Comment: But fmodos, by passing in the records equals method and comparing strictly the records of both objects am I not bypassing this issue? maybe i am misunderstanding you.

Comment: What are the equals and hashcode methods for Record, then, since you are delegating equality there?

Comment: @JudgeMental this is already included in the post. The hashCode and equals methods are the ones for Record.

Comment: Sorry @AKon; I couldn't tell that at first glance.  What happens when you step into the get() call?  You should see the hashCode get calculated, then you should see the map look up that hashCode, and then you should see a call to equals().  What are you actually seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null){ 
        return false; 
    }
    else if(o instanceof Record){
        Record r = (Record) o;
        return this.entity.equals(r.entity) && this.relation.equals(r.relation) && this.property.equals(r.property);
    }

    else return false;
}
```

your Entry equals method may have some problem,what's the definition of relation?
the relation must be overwrite equals() and hashCode()

It's great to put all your code here,what's your main's definition?
and In your code there are many places contains maybe null pointer bug

Answer (score 0):

your hashcode function might have a problem when setting the int to 0 (int h = 0) ... a good explanation can be found in Josh Bloch's Effectiv Java book (item 8).

Here is an example:

@Override
public int hashCode() {

```
int result = 17;

// this line should change depending on your fields
// let say you have a string property that is not null
result = 31 * result + property.hashCode();

return result;
```

}

... you can also use a library like Guava

@Override
public int hashCode() {

```
return Objects.hashCode(this.property1, this.property2);
```

}